render preview looks different to rendered image
i'm creating a short toonshaded animation for a high school project and had some questions about the rendered preview vs. final image.
the rendered preview looks exactly how i want it to look with all the shadows and everything, but the rendered image looks way flatter than the preview. but in some scenes the final render looks fine. how can i fix this to make the final render look like the preview?
(using eevee)

Hello, make sure that your lights are enabled for preview and render in the Outliner, also make sure that the Scene World option is enabled in the Viewport Shading panel?
